# highcharts stackLabels updating issue

Tags: highcharts

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/stacklabels-enabled/) from highcharts `stackLabels` example. 
Once you disable a series in the legend, `stackLabels` are updated but still shows the old total values as well. I guess a correct behavior should be showing only the values (**sum**) of enabled series. Is this a bug?

```
yAxis: {
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column:{
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug, but already resolved on master branch, see: http://jsfiddle.net/hLLjj/

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.js"></script>
```